# Was the pastor a part of the admission committee?

Tags: analysis, rudy

In the movie [Rudy (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108002/), Rudy is helped by a priest in in getting admission to a local college (Holy Cross), later hoping to transfer to Notre Dame. After two years at Holy Cross and three rejections from Notre Dame, Rudy is finally admitted.
The movie subtly suggests that priest may be a member of the admission committee, but never explicitly mentioned this.

Is there any reference in or outside the movie to this?

Comment: You might want to contact him and ask.  www.rudyruettiger.com